# How do I run a a typescript / tsx file from nextjs project in terminal using ts-node?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I frequently like to use `ts-node` to execute a single file.

I'm looking to be able to run anything like `ts-node ./page/home.tsx`.

I'm having issues doing so within my nextjs project.

```
export const WidgetList = createWidget<ButtonListProps>(WidgetListProps)
                                      ^
TypeError: (0 , Widget_1.createWidget) is not a function
```

My tsconfig.json looks like this, having to swap out the commented ones that are the default for a nextjs project.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    // "module": "esnext",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    // "jsx": "preserve",
    "jsx": "react",
    "incremental": true,
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Without `module` commented I get `Cannot use import statement outside a module`
Without `jsx` commented I get a jsx error

## Update

**The app fully functions with all imports.**

I'm not sure I understand why node is not able to track this import.

I've since added a new `tsconfig.node.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
}
```

and I try to execute any file in my project:

```
ts-node --project ./tsconfig.node.json ./components/widget/Widget.tsx
```

I get the same kind of error.

Comment: Where does createWidget come from ?

Comment: I have a file that exports it "<root>/components/widget/Widget.tsx"

Comment: What's the use case for running a React component file with `ts-node`?

Comment: @juliomalves I'd like to test the file and console.log a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately nextjs uses webpack to build and so you can't execute the code with `ts-node`. One way to execute a file is to build it then run it with node. This worked for my case. The issue here is that the file needs to be within `pages` or `pages/api` this will 'fool' next into building an executable file. All dependencies of pages/api seem to be bundled into chunks.

```
yarn next build    
node ./.next/server/pages/api/initialize.js
```

In my specific case, I am seeding a database with default react prop information, a fringe idea. Because I am importing front-end files to use the on the backend, in a script, I can't use `ts-node`.

Answer (score -2):

You can run any typescript file with `npx ts-node filename.ts`

TSX files need to be processed by NextJS so to use them they need to be imported.

```
> import { Component } from "Component"
```

Comment: I am importing dependencies already and the front-end app works. The issue is node is not recognizing the export from my file correctly. 

This comment is problematic because you cant include .tsx extensions for typescript. You get the error: An import path cannot end with a '.tsx' extension